# Updating column value with max of 2 values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to update a column with the max value of either the current col value OR the new value I pass. In pseudocode:

update table1 set employees=MAX(employees,30) where id=23

So, in the above case:
if employees is currently 20, the new value will BECOME 30
if employees is currently 50, the value will REMAIN 50

How can I do that? Is there a simple standard function for that available (I'd rather not use case statement)

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my curiousity, but why would you change a column to it's current value ? If you need, i can find a script to slow down your server much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update table1
set employees = (case when employees < 30 then 30 else employees end)
where id = 23
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `where` clause to update only rows with `employees < 30`:

```
update table1
set employees = 30
where id = 23 and employees < 30
```

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestions but not exactly what I need. My mistake, I should have clarified better: I want to run the MAX statement on more than 1 column (up to as much as 100).

So a statement would look more like this:
UPDATE table1 SET 
employees=MAX(employees,30),
streetname=MAX(streetname,'Abbey road') 
turnover=MAX(turnover,500000) 
WHERE id=23

Comment: @Floran, in that case, I think my answer will work for you, You just need multiple `case` statements. The `case` statement does the same thing as your MAX function. Although @Andomar still has the better solution if you are only updating one column.